# How to wait for the android service to get started before continuing with rest of the code?

Tags: android, service

I'm doing something like this.

Read some entries from the UI and pass it on to the service after clicking a Button. After that my activity would launch other apps and do a series of actions. My Service in the meantime would keep performing certain actions in a HandlerThread until I stop the service from the activity.

My issue is the service doesn't get started until the app completes all the execution. Once the execution is over, I relaunch the application and the service starts now. Here are the logs that I found.

```
ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.myapp/.MyService in 1000ms
ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{feb859c u0 com.example.myapp/.MyService}
ActivityManager: Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{ffc2825 u0 com.example.myapp/.MyAppActivity t10}
WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{b5d67d6 u0 d0 p8877 com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyAppActivity}
SurfaceFlinger: id=102 Removed com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyAppActivity (6/12)
PowerManagerService: [api] handleWakeLockDeath : release WakeLock : PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  'MyApp' (uid=2000, pid=8877, ws=null) (elapsedTime=33507)
SurfaceFlinger: id=102 Removed com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyAppActivity (-2/12)
ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{ffc2825 u0 com.example.myapp/.MyAppActivity t10}: app died, no saved state
InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: name='b5d67d6 com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyAppActivity (server)', fd=415
SurfaceFlinger: id=102 Removed com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyAppActivity (-2/12)
MultiWindowPolicy: adjustStackFocus: r=ActivityRecord{18ffddd u0 com.example.myapp/.MyAppActivity t-1} multiWindowStyle=MultiWindowStyle{type=0, zone=ZONE_ds=null, isNull=false, isolatedCenterPoint=Point(0, 0), scale=0.0, specificTaskId=-1}
WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{d067c2823 token=Token{f969d52 ActivityRecord{18ffddd u0 com.example.myapp/.MyAppActivity t10}}} to stack=2 task=
```

Can anybody please help me with the same? I press a "Button". Service should get started and only then that rest of the code should get executed.

Answer (score 1):

To start a service, do as below which will give you callback once service started and bound to it

```
context.bindService(new Intent(context, YourService.class), new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
          //service started and bound
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
          //service disconnected
        }
    }, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: I need to put this code in my Activity and it would ensure that rest of the code won't get executed before the service is started right? And also I don't need to use startService to start the service anymore?

Comment: whatever task you want to do after service is started, do that in `onServiceConnected()` method. You don't need to use `startService()`

Answer (score 0):

First, inside onCreate() method define your button, and start service on button click:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourService.class);
        intent.putExtra("your_key1", "your_data1");
        intent.putExtra("your_key2", "your_data2");
        intent.putExtra("your_key3", "your_data3");
        startService(intent);
    }
});
```

In the onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) of your service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String data1 = intent.getStringExtra("your_key1");
    String data2 = intent.getStringExtra("your_key2");
    String data3 = intent.getStringExtra("your_key3");
    // do your stuff here using the passed data
    // p.s. if your work is too long, then do them inside a thread
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm already doing, but my onClick has got a lot of things like starting other apps and doing some tests on them. So my Service doesn't get started at all and the App gets killed at the end. I'm unable to ensure that the service is already started before I do other things in onClick.

Comment: then on button click show some not-cancellable progress dialog, and when all of your work gets finished, cancel the progress dialog. Thus you can make sure that your service is started. Do the work in another thread